# ffmpeg decode raw h264 distorted or gray image

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, libav

I need to decode an H264 stream that comes from a live DVR camera.
To facilitate the example, I stored the RAW stream from the DVR camera in the following file (test.h264): http://f.zins.com.br/test.h264

To decode the live stream, I followed the following ffmpeg example: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/decode_video.c

If I open the .h264 test with VLC, the images look perfect.
If you decode the .h264 test with ffmpeg using **avformat_open_input** and **avformat_find_stream_info**, the images also look perfect.

But if I decode using the https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/decode_video.c example, the images are all distorted. I think this happens because along with the H264 stream can have audio together.

Enabling the debugging of ffmpeg, it shows a lot of the following errors:

```
[h264 @ 092a9b00] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 092a9b00] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 092a9b00] Invalid NAL unit 0, skipping.
[h264 @ 092a9b00] error while decoding MB 16 1, bytestream -28
[h264 @ 092a9b00] Invalid NAL unit 8, skipping.
[h264 @ 092a9b00] Invalid NAL unit 8, skipping.
[h264 @ 092a9b00] Invalid NAL unit 8, skipping.
```

Is there a way for me to only filter the **video** and **ignore the audio** from a live stream?
Otherwise, is there any solution to decode the test.h264 using the decode_video.c example without distorting the frames?

The distorted frame sometimes looks like the image below, and sometimes it gets almost all gray.
[image: distorted frame]

Comment: .h264 is supposed to be a raw stream and contains no audio. What this is, is a MPEG-PS with a single stream. Remux to a raw stream: `ffmpeg -i test.h264 -c copy raw.h264` and use that.

Comment: I already did that and it worked. The problem is that I can not do the same with live stream.
In live stream I get the bytes exactly as they are stored in test.h264, and I have those problems to decode.

Comment: So, you'll need to demux and read packets using mpegps

Comment: Can you help me get started doing live stream demux? I do not know how to start, because all the examples that I see the demux is done through a file.

Comment: Why don't you simply skip corrupted frames?

Comment: @MikeVersteeg these are not corrupted frames, it's a wrapper around h264 stream that must be carefully stripped away

Comment: How do I skip this by decoding the live stream? Remember that to process the live stream I'm using av_parser_parse2.

Comment: I believe you can simply use `av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt)`

Comment: How to create fmt_ctx from a live stream instead of a file / URL?

Comment: You probably have *some* URL for your camera, e.g. `"rtsp://10.0.0.12:8554/test.h264"`, same as what do you pass to VLC.

Comment: Or, you can wrap your live stream in custom AVIOContext, similar to [this example](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.5/avio_reading_8c-example.html).

Comment: @Alex Cohn, it worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please remove "solved" from your title and move your solution to its own answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stream has mpeg wrapper around raw h264 packets, and we need to demux them first. If you cannot provide a URL with some [protocol supported by ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html) (e.g. **udp://**) like, you should build custom **AVIOContext** for your live stream and pass it to

```
avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

similar to [this example](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.5/avio_reading_8c-example.html).

Now you can start the usual demuxer loop with

```
av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt)
```